# Minimizing Surface Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, numerical-methods

I have a tensor-product $B$-spline surface. I have been able to determine all the control points
of the surface so that all the points are given as a function of only one of these points, that we call $P$. Varying $P$ I obtain different surfaces and I want the surface with minimum curvature. How can I procede to find the $P$ which minimize the curvature? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote your surface by $\mathbf S(u,v, P)$, for $0 \le u \le 1$, $0 \le v \le 1$. Clearly you can write an expression for the curvature $\kappa(u,v, P)$ at the parameter values $(u,v)$, using various partial derivatives of $\mathbf S(u,v,P)$. One complication is that you have to decide what you mean by "curvature" -- at any given point, there is mean curvature, Gaussian curvature, etc, etc.

Then, what you're looking for is the value of $P$ that minimises
$$
\min\{\kappa(u,v,P): 0 \le u \le 1, 0 \le v \le 1\} 
$$
I don't see any clever way to tackle this -- you just have to pass the problem to your favorite numerical optimization package, and hope that it produces something useful.

In general, I think this is a pretty difficult problem. Even calculating b-spline curves with minimum curvature is fairly difficult, and the surface case is much harder. Sorry I can't be more helpful.